# res.redirect to a post endpoint?

Tags: node.js, express, redirect, post

I am working with Node.js and have an endpoint which handles user 'logins'.  A database is queried and based upon the results of the query the user is allowed to log in.  I wish to use a 'res.redirect' upon login success similar as here (adapted from Express documentation) in order to pass some information about the user as returned from the database call:

```
app.post('/login', function (req, res) {

//do stuff here to check database and log the user in...

//then set a path to redirect to an endpoint such as "/users/:email/username/:name/joindate/:joined"

res.redirect('/users/' + "me@somehost.com" + '/username/' + "Frank" + '/joindate/' + "11-30-2019")

//sample output would be... req.params: { "email": "me@somehost.com", "username": "Frank", "joindate": "11-30-2019" }
}
```

My issue is by using this approach, a GET request will be generated...which is undesirable since the passed client information could contain sensitive information (such as email) and therefore I do not wish to use a GET, which would place sensitive info 'in the clear'.  Is it instead possible to use a POST in the request URL...and handle it as such:

```
app.post('/users/:email/username/:name/joindate/:joined', function (req, res) {
console.log(req.params);
res.render('accounts', {email: req.params[0], username: req.params[1], joined: req.params[2]});
})
```

Possible?  I am having trouble realizing this...how does one redirect to a POST endpoint?  Any help greatly appreciated.  As I understand using a POST would allow the sensitive info to be passed securely.  I thank you in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: You can't use `res.redirect()` to cause a browser to do a POST.  The browser just doesn't work that way.  Why not just render the data you want the client to have from the original request rather than trying to do a second POST?  FYI, POSTs are not more secure for data transmitted from server to client.  No difference there between GET and POST at all.

Comment: I wanted to use a redirect so the page in the browser changes.  I was under the impression a POST (or PUT) place the data in the body rather than in the URL as a GET request would...therefore prevent the info from being exposed.  Thank you for your reply.

Comment: POST puts the data sent from client to server in the body instead of the URL.  Data coming back from the server is the same whether POST or GET.  I can't tell what you're trying to protect.  If you described exactly what you're trying to protect, we could help you better.  There is no such thing as a redirect that makes the browser do a POST so that is not an option.

Comment: Yes by not having the data in the URL does that not introduce a level of protection?  I simply do not want to pass the info such as ':email', ':name', and ':joined' or whatever (as in my post above) within the URL using a GET...is there no work-around?  I simply wish to render an .ejs page using the data returned from the database call AND make the URL in the browser change...rather than being the same as previous.  If there is no way to accomplish that I guess I will just live with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can't use `res.redirect()` to instruct the browser to POST the data back to the server.  That's just not a browser or http feature.

Here are the options I can think of:

1. Render the result directly from the original post and live with the URL that it shows.
2. Render the result directly from the original post and use client-side Javascript to change the displayed URL.
3. Store the data in a server-side session and redirect to a URL where the server gets the data from the session.
4. Store the data in a cookie and redirect to a URL where the server gets the data from the cookie.
5. Store the data in a temporary server-side data store that is keyed by a unique ID and redirect to a URL that has the unique iD in the URL so the server can read that key and get the data out of the temporary store that corresponds to that key.  You will have to age out this temporary store so data does not accumulate.
6. Submit the original form via Javascript instead of a browser submitted form where the receiving Javascript can get the response URL and data in a JSON response, take the data out and POST it back to the server.

**Recommendations / Issues**

My preference would probably be #6 because it keeps the server stateless in this regard and has no possible concurrency issues.

If you never want to sent that data to the client (perhaps the most secure), then I'd probably go for #2 or #5 as it keeps the data entirely server-side and has no concurrency issues.

Options #3 and #4 have a possible concurrency issue if the same client is doing two similar transactions in different browser windows/tabs because the state you store only belongs to one of those windows, but is tied to a browser, not a window so they could overwrite each other.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions.  I was thinking of using session variables.  I am using the 'express-session' module therefore it is probably best to set variables such as "req.session.email = user.email", "req.session.firstname = user.firstname", etc...  then I can redirect to another URL and access the session variables to populate the render of a new .ejs page.  I guess this would be reasonably secure and the simplest way of accomplishing this.  Once again I thank you for your time and input.

Comment: @Pangit - Session variables are not my favorite because there are possible concurrency problems if you're putting temporary values in the session and more than one window/browser could be doing a similar transaction.  You will also need to make sure and age that info out of the session so it doesn't stay there too long.  My preference would probably be #6 because it keeps the server stateless and has no concurrency issues.

Comment: @Pangit - I added a few of my personal thoughts to the answer on choosing one of the different options.

Comment: Thank you for all of your information.  I suppose #2 would not be too difficult to implement.  I am using a data store for my sessions...I suppose I could utilize that to implement option #5 as well.  I would just need to do some research on how I can 'pull' information from the data store...not sure if it is just a parse of the text file using the 'fs' module tools or something else...you are a wealth of information...!